# What's the preferred Java convention for naming static constructor methods

Tags: java

What is the preferred convention for naming static constructor methods? For example, say I have an `Error` class, which has a single constructor which simply initialises the fields, and then some static constructor methods:

```
class Error {
    static Error xxxx(String msg) {
        return new Error(msg, -1);
    }

    static Error xxxx(String msg, int line) {
        return new Error(msg, line);
    }

    final String msg;
    final int line;

    private Error(String msg, int line) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.line = line
    }
}
```

What should I name the `xxxx` methods. Possibilities include:

1. `valueOf` - some Java classes follow this, e.g. `Integer.valueOf`, but is this only used for boxing primitives?
2. `of` - more terse. `Error.of(msg, i)` seems readable.
3. `error` - some pros and cons - see below.
4. `create` - gives undue emphasis to the mechanism (create something) instead of the intent (give me a value). For instance, some implementations may cache and re-use values, meaning something isn't always actually created as such.
5. `createError` - wordy, and same issue as `create`.

I tend to code in a functional style, and, possibly as a consequence, my preference was #3, partly because if I static import `Error` then I can call it simply as `error(msg, i)`, which seems readable and mimics actual constructor usage. However, it may cause confusion with local variables of the same name. For example `error = error(msg, i);` looks confusing.

I would be interested in seeing evidence or arguments in favour of a particular approach, rather than simple "I like xxx" answers.

Comment: asError? Just like Arrays.asList will return a list.

Comment: Maybe `getInstance()` but this maybe implies a Singleton so `createError()` would be better or you put more information into the method names like `createSimpleError()`, `createErrorWithLocation()` or such

Comment: And btw return new Error(msg); would not wok because Error(string) is not defined

Comment: @JClassic: thanks, typo fixed.

Comment: @mithandir: Not a fan of `getInstance` - it suggests there is only one value, i.e. a singleton.

Comment: @mithrandir I find getInstance would be better suited for singletons, since that's the only time I've seen them used

Comment: @JClassic: `asXXX` methods suggest they are converting a value from one form to another.

Comment: @jon-hanson yup that is right :P I only considered that there was a string, such as "a string as a error"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the recent JDK additions are a good indication, then you could look at [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html):

> The API has a relatively large surface area in terms of number of
>   methods. This is made manageable through the use of consistent method
>   prefixes.
>
> - `of` - static factory method
> - `parse` - static factory method focussed on parsing
> - [...]

`of` looks like a reasonable candidate for your use case, but what probably matters more than the choice is consistency.

Comment: I don't think parse is a good idea, because it would suggest the parameters and return value is similar, such as Integer.parse(String), which returns an integer value from a string

Comment: @JClassic assylias actually suggests `of`. The above excerpt makes clear `parse` should be used for constructor methods which actually parse something.

Answer (score 3):

In "Effective Java", in addition to "valueOf" and "of" that you've already mentioned, Joshua Bloch proposes the following:

1. **getInstance**
2. **newInstance**
3. **get**Type (i.e. getError)
4. **new**Type (i.e. newError)

Answer (score 1):

A good name for this is `newError(...)`. It suggest the class is also a factory for itself.

Comment: I think this falls afoul of the same criticism I levelled at `createXXX`.

Comment: Well, I find `createError` and `newError` both fine.

Answer (score 0):

`valueOf` and `of` can be used when the factory method uses some kind of cache such that the method invocation doesn't necessary create new instance.

`newClassName` or `createClassName` is for general factory methods where it always tries to create an instance.